# Why am I getting <string> node in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string item in titl)
{
    //new instance of Data
    Type keyType = item.GetType();
    XmlSerializer keySerializer = GetTypeSerializer(keyType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("tTime");
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("tText");
    }
    if (keyType != typeof(string)) { writer.WriteAttributeString("type", keyType.AssemblyQualifiedName); }
    keySerializer.Serialize(writer, item);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

and

```
#region " GetTypeSerializer "

private static readonly Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer> _serializers = new Dictionary<string, XmlSerializer>();
private static readonly object _deadbolt = new object();
private XmlSerializer GetTypeSerializer(string type)
{
    if (!_serializers.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        lock (_deadbolt)
        {
            if (!_serializers.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                _serializers.Add(type,new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType(type)));

            }
        }
    }
    return _serializers[type];
}

#endregion
```

I am getting XML as:

```
<item>
  <Data>
    <tText>
      <string>6 resources every xxx should use tips #xl8</string>
    </tText>
    <tTime>
      <string>Tue Oct 28 09:43:22 +0000 2014</string>
    </tTime>
    <tText>
      <string>Tips for learning a new language </string>
    </tText>
    <tTime>
      <string>Fri Oct 24 16:35:30 +0000 2014</string>
    </tTime>
    <tText>
      <string>#Voiceover or #Subtitles</string>
    </tText>
    <tTime>
      <string>Thu Oct 23 17:34:15 +0000 2014</string>
    </tTime>
  </Data>
</item>
```

I am having a string from which I am creating XML file but
I am unable to make out from where is this string tag coming? may be it's from somewhere by keyType but I didn't get it how? I do not want this string node to appear in this XML

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: @jdweng in short it is the <string> node that I am getting in my XML. and I do not want this to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is telling the serializer to `Serialize` an element of type string, instead of just writing text.

Use [XmlWriter.WriteString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [XmlSerializer.Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163161(v=vs.110).aspx) - instead of :

```
keySerializer.Serialize(writer, item);
```

use

```
writer.WriteString(item);
```

Specifically, this :

```
var titl = new List<string> {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

int i = 0;
foreach (string item in titl)
{
    //new instance of Data
    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("tTime");
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("tText");
    }
    writer.WriteString(item);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Will produce this

```
<tText>aaa</tText>
<tTime>bbb</tTime>
<tText>ccc</tText>
```

Comment: What did you actually write? If you check the example of [XmlWriter.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that a sequence of `StartElement,WriteString,EndElement` will produce `<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>`

Comment: You do realize, that `item` is always a string so there is no need to use a type-specific XmlSerializer?

Comment: Your code `foreach (string item in titl)` means that `item` is always a string. It doesn't matter whether `titl` is an array, List<string> or Queue<string>. In fact, nothing changes if I change `new[]` to `new List<string>`. Please post the actual code you used

Comment: ya i added foreach loop later but its working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the XmlSerializer class explicitly serializes a document, and a document(well formed) contains a root element. 
So, the XmlSerializer seems to take the typename as element-Name for the root element.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but you propably can't. The Serializer serializes an object as XML-Document and that's it. You seem to want to construct one document from several strings - using the XmlWriter like Panagiotis suggested seems to be adequate.